# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'instance' and 'int'

Tags: python

I am recieving this error multiple times within my code. I it occurring when I am using:

`pos -= 1`

The error of course is: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'instance' and 'int'`

Any help is appriciated!

```
def DELETE(pos, lst) :
    temp = FIRST(lst)
    # move to just before pos
    if pos == 0 :
        lst.head = temp.nxt
    elif pos == END(lst) :
        if temp.nxt == None :
            lst = MAKENULL()
        else :
            while (temp.nxt).nxt :
                temp = temp.nxt
            temp.nxt = None
    else :
        while pos - 1 > 0 :
            temp = temp.nxt
            pos -= 1
        first = temp
        second = temp.nxt
        first.nxt = second.nxt
        lst.cur = lst.head
```

Comment: `pos` is the instance of some class. Look further up the exception stack to the callers to see where its being set incorrectly. Catch the exception and print the name of the class (`os.__class__.__name__) which gives more of a hint of what is being assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting depends only marginally on the code you show -- it's mostly about what `pos` is -- apparently an instance of an old-style Python 2 class not implementing special methods to try to fake being an integer (in particular, `__isub__` for in-place subtraction.